# How to get a job in the Reverse Engineering community?

Tags: career-advice

Just curious if there are any resources for finding a job being a Reverse Engineering specialist.  I have done some RE work in the past, and I find that I enjoy the work, but haven't really been able to find any job boards, or rather the typical job boards seldom mention "Information Security" positions let alone people who specialize in Reverse Engineering.

Comment: @Nirlzr, so your saying everything asked and answered in that question three years ago is still relevant?

Comment: I skimmed over it just now since you asked, and I can't think of anything to important to add or a shift that will require significantly different responses. Even if there was some new possible answer, Stack Exchange encourages late responses over asking new questions. By all means, feel free to correct me!

Comment: This kind of questions is not a good fit for this site anyway since it doesn't have one answer.